# Granting access to a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, mac-osx, iis-6, vmware-fusion

I have an internal website running on IIS 6 that denies access to everyone except for a few select IP addresses.  This is set by going to "Directory Security -> IP addressees and domain name restrictions" and entering the ip addresses that are allowed to access.

When I try to access this site from my laptop after VPNing in, I can get to the site.  But if I try to access the site from a VM running on my laptop I get a 403 error.  I have checked the IIS logs and don't see anything that would point me to what IP address it is denying access to.

I have tried looking at the output of `ifconfig` on my laptop (macbook) and `ipconfig` on my VM (Windows Server 2003) but adding those IPs does not seem to grant access.  I am using NAT on my VM.

Does anyone know how I can either grant access to my VM or figure out what IP my VM is using to access the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the VM to used bridged mode instead of NAT.  This would have the VM pull an IP from the network (closest DHCP source) and you could try and test with that IP to see if you get the same results.

Comment: Gave it a shot but it didn't work.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but are you trying to access the site after setting up the VPN tunnel inside the VM?

Comment: Actually I was wrong when I said I was connecting from inside the VM.  I had made a VPN connection from my laptop, but not within the VM itself.  Once I did this I was able to access.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm somewhat curious as to why it wouldn't let you connect through the NAT then, but I'm glad it worked.